# Multiple ajax requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, ajax, parallel-processing, blob

I have a bunch of images that I want to read with ajax.
If I know the url of each image how can I make 3 image ajax requests simultaneously, then get the next 3 until I have them all?

This is my ajax function for one image

```
  var image_url = images[i];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      console.log(xhr.response, typeof xhr.response);

    }
  }

  xhr.open('GET', image_url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
```

Comment: any reason to limit to 3 simultaneous requests?

Comment: to not overload the server

Comment: You're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). The solutions below utilize JQuery, but this can be done with vanilla JS

Answer (score 2):

If you set `async` to true, you can fire multiple at the same time. The browser will limit as to how many at a time, depending on which one being used.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "foo2.php"
    });
```

`async` with ajax works opposite to what you would think.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the URLs for each image in an array.
If you have no qualms with jQuery, you should use $.get as it will help a lot of handling in this case. Then call it within a recursive function. This is pseudo code, i haven't tested it.

```
var imageUrls = [];//populate with your URLs
getImage(0);
getImage(1);
getImage(2);


var getImage = function(iteration){
  $.get(imageUrls[iteration], function(data){
     //handle the image
     //call the function again with the next index
     getImage(iteration+3);
  });

}
```